# jQuery hover on tables

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

The html structure is like this:

```
<tr class="row-1 row-first">
  <td class="col-1 col-first">
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-logo-image"></div>
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-logo-title"></div>
  <td class="col-2">
<td class="col-3 col-last">
```

".views-field views-field-field-logo-title" is a title that will appear over the image only when I hover the table.

This is the CSS for the elements:

```
.view-clone-of-logo td {
    width:230px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
}

.views-field-field-logo-title {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #B2D433;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 130px;
    margin: -5000px 0 0;
    opacity: 0.9; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 220px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

I've managed to display the title on hover with this code:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.view-clone-of-logo td').hover(function() {
            $('.view-clone-of-logo .views-field-field-logo-title').css("margin-top", "-155px");
        }, function() {
            $('.view-clone-of-logo .views-field-field-logo-title').css("margin-top", "-5000px");
        });


        });

}(jQuery));
```

BUT, when I hover all the titles are displaying over the images.

Lets say I'm hovering on the first row/first column and I want to display the title from that column.

How can I display the title from a specific column?

Comment: where is the `view-clone-of-logo` in the html?

Comment: Try using `$(this).find('.views-field-field-logo-title').css("margin-top", "-155px");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.view-clone-of-logo td').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('.views-field-field-logo-title').css("margin-top", "-155px");
        }, function() {
            $(this).find('.views-field-field-logo-title').css("margin-top", "-5000px");
        });


        });

}(jQuery));
```

You said to jQuery : find all `.view-clone-of-logo .views-field-field-logo-title` and do that, when you wanna say : find the `.views-field-field-logo-title` in the element that is hovered.

Comment: I've just tried and it's working great! Thank you very much. Thank you for the explaining.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Feel free to mark it as resolved then.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that in 6 minutes :)

Comment: I'd say the only issue with this is that its creating a hover event for every <td>, which isn't very efficient. You're better creating 1 hover event for the table and on hover checking the tag name to see if its a <td>, then doing what you need to do

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in pure CSS

```
.view-clone-of-logo td:hover .views-field-field-logo-title {
    margin-top: -155px;
}
```

Comment: It's surely the best way.